# No page numbers in the appendix of book

Tags: appendices, books

I am using the package appendix in book. I cannot see page numbers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla
\begin{appendices}
Bla bla
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Please, tell me:

1. What can I do so the page numbering continues also in the appendix?
2. How can I remove the page "Apendices"?

Comment: I see page numbers; the “Appendix” page doesn't appear if you remove the `page` option.